# vim regex to search for lines containing string1 AND string2

Tags: vim, regular-expression

How in vim/vi can I search for all lines that contain string1 and string2, where either string can appear anywhere on the line separated by whitespace and possibly other words?

I would also like to know how to do this using the less pager search (/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find two words in either order in a line:

```
/.*red\&.*blue
```

or

```
/\(red.*blue\)\|\(blue.*red\)
```

Other tools use a slightly different regular expression dialect; in *less*, you'd use:

```
/(red.*blue|blue.*red)
```

Comment: Looks good, where is less' regex syntax documented?

Comment: I think it just uses `man 7 regex`.

Comment: You also have `\v`, that is, `/\v(red|blue)`.